# disable a all the properties of a css selector

Tags: css

I have a css rule

```
    .lp-caption {
      -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
      -moz-border-left-colors: none;
      -moz-border-right-colors: none;
      -moz-border-top-colors: none;
      background-attachment: scroll;
      background-clip: border-box;
      background-color: #FCFCFC;
      background-image: none;
      background-origin: padding-box;
      background-position: 0 0;
      background-repeat: repeat;
      background-size: auto auto;
      border-bottom-color: #EEEEEE;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
      border-bottom-style: solid;
      border-bottom-width: 1px;
      border-image-outset: 0 0 0 0;
      border-image-repeat: stretch stretch;
      border-image-slice: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
      border-image-source: none;
      border-image-width: 1 1 1 1;
      border-left-color-ltr-source: physical;
      border-left-color-rtl-source: physical;
      border-left-color-value: #EEEEEE;
      border-left-style-ltr-source: physical;
      border-left-style-rtl-source: physical;
      border-left-style-value: solid;
      border-left-width-ltr-source: physical;
      border-left-width-rtl-source: physical;
      border-left-width-value: 1px;
      border-right-color-ltr-source: physical;
      border-right-color-rtl-source: physical;
      border-right-color-value: #EEEEEE;
      border-right-style-ltr-source: physical;
      border-right-style-rtl-source: physical;
      border-right-style-value: solid;
      border-right-width-ltr-source: physical;
      border-right-width-rtl-source: physical;
      border-right-width-value: 1px;
      border-top-color: #EEEEEE;
      border-top-left-radius: 5px;
      border-top-right-radius: 5px;
      border-top-style: solid;
      border-top-width: 1px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 3px #EEEEEE;
      max-width: 100%;
      padding-bottom: 0;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 0;
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
```

I can't change the CSS Stylesheet but I can apply css changes through other means. So I want to make the html complete ignore all the rules for this selector .lp-caption.

Is there any way I can do that like `.lp-caption{none}`

Comment: You could display: none the lp-caption if you want to hide it or overwrite for every rule you want to change.

Comment: The only solution is to override them all. There is no such thing like you are asking I think.

Comment: `removeClass` of `jQuery` is probably the straight forward solution. You can add an empty class by using `addClass` then.

Comment: i think display:none will not show the content. THere are so many properties with padding or border, can they be overriden with mentioning single property

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible to remove them, you would have to override each property to your needs. What you can is to add class to this element (with javascript) and define different css rules to that class.

Comment: I agree 100% with this.

Answer (score 1):

This is the ugly way of doing it I guess:

```
.lp-caption {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
border: none;
background-image: none;
background-color: transparent;
}
```